# login form using php, mysql and checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project in php, but I am stuck.   I have a login form with 3 checkboxes and 2 text fields for username and password. Each checkbox represents a user, such as admin, student and lecturer. So when a user wants to login, he has to provide his username, password and check one of the checkboxes. So if the user is stored in the database as a student, he has to check the student checkbox and press the submit button. Then while processing, the system will check if this user is stored as student. If that is the case he can now login. Otherwise the login form comes back.

I have an array of checkboxes:

```
<Input type = "checkbox" name=" cool[] "value= "student">
<Input type = "checkbox" name=" cool[]" value=" admin">
<Input type = "checkbox" name=" cool[]" value=" lecturer">
<Input type = "submit" name= "submit" value= "login">
```

In the php part I have:

```
If (isset($_POST['submit'] ){
    $user=$_POST['textfield_value_username'] ;
    $pass=$_POST['textfield_value_passeord'] ;
    $check=$_POST['cool'] ;
    foreach ($check  as  $kio) {
        $d= "select * from table-name
            where = $user = 'value_from _db' , " 
        $pass= 'value_from_db' and $kio='value_in-db';
        if($d) {
            // do something...
       }
    }
}
```

This is an overview of the code. When I try it it doesn't work, but when I do `select *` and I use only `$user` and `$pass` it works. When I use only `select * .... Where ... $Kio ..` it works also. But when I combine all, it doesn't work and it doesn't give any error.

So, I don't know if I was clear, but this is all about the problem I have. I have been searching on internet but I got no result.

Comment: Please correct your code block (type Ctrl + K for the code area) otherwise no body will be able to help you.

Comment: Not exactly userfriendly

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, your question is not good and has severe problems: First of, make sure to write proper English (one dot is enough and using paragraphs makes it much more readable). Also, your problem statement is quite unclear. Please take a look at the help section about how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why would you want to use checkboxes to determine the type of user that logs in. I suggest putting this in the database as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to provide radio button in place of checkboxes because an user can be either admin or student/lecturer so change this to radio button and don't make any array just simply fetch values and jion them by **AND** condition in query

Answer (score 0):

It's not work, because there are syntax errors in your code. It should be like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = $_POST['textfield_value_username'];
    $pass = $_POST['textfield_value_passeord'];
    $check = $_POST['cool'];
    foreach ($check as $kio) {
        $d = "select * from table-name where 'value_from _db' = '".$user."'"
            . " AND  'value_from_db' = '".$pass."'"
            . " AND 'value_in-db' = '".$kio."'";
        //Query and fetch here
        if ($row) {
// do something 
        }
    }
}
```